# Binding to IEnumerator?

Tags: wpf

I have two buttons, (next button and previous button) that moves to the next or previous record, I am using IEnumerator for this and added the MovePrevious method. Upon moving records, I am manually populating the data of this FlowDocumentPageViewer. I am thinking, is there a way that I can just bind the FlowDocumentPageViewer to a collection or something so that when I traverse records then it will automatically reflected in the viewer?

Comment: can you not use an `ItemControl` and then bind the `ItemsSource` property to your collection?

Comment: Isn't ItemControl for listboxes, etc?

Comment: `ItemsControl` is for anything that presents a list of items, no matter what the visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [collection views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) for that, they have a current item that you can bind to (in [binding syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) `{Binding Collection/}`). To change the current item use [`MoveCurrentToNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrenttonext.aspx)/[`Previous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrenttoprevious.aspx).